# Github keeps performing external checks even after removing the webhook

Tags: github, github-api

We have some checks for our Github repo that run in Jenkins via a Webhook. We moved them to another CI server but, even after disabling/removing the Jenkins Webhook from the repo, the old PRs still triggers the old Jenkins checks and fail. New PRs are not affected.

How can we clean or remove this old/stale checks for existing PRs?

Answer (score 0):

After struggling here, we found out that the checks are tied to the commit. So, even if you create new branches or PRs, if they share the same commit, the checks will be reused.

After pushing a new commit, the checks were refreshed and the stale ones were removed.